# I have a wpf mvvm application, where do I put Database or Sockets?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

as I explained in the title I have a wpf app with only one View. The model is Note. In the view you can add notes. Those notes must be sended to a sockets server or saved on a Database, my question is: where do I put the code related to the action of saving notes? In model, viewmodel or in another class?

This question may be trivial, but I have just started up with wpf+mvvm and I am a bit lost.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Saving or loading model data would be located in the `model` or a class used by the model. That would be the first `M` of [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm)

Answer (score 1):

viewmodel is the inter-mediator between view and model.**viewmodel is the place where you code the functionality you want in your application** whereas model is the core class describing the entities of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to separate anything to do with database accessing to different classes, or even another project and referencing those classes there. depending of the size of your project its a good way to make maintaining the database actions. it also allows you to generalize the database actions. in the end its up to you where you want to place it.